# How to access environment variables in typescript format serverless files?

Tags: typescript, lambda, serverless

I’ve used this excellent template to get going with Node and typescript serverless/lib/plugins/create/templates/aws-nodejs-typescript at master · serverless/serverless · GitHub

In the handler definition I’m trying to reference environment variables

When I print out the variable, there is no interpolation. The variable is still ${env.CONFIG_TABLE} with the braces

"CONFIG_TABLE":"${env.CONFIG_TABLE}
I would like to use environment variables for CI and .env for local development.

```
const serverlessConfiguration: AWS = {
  service: 'trial-service',
  frameworkVersion: '2',
  useDotenv: true,
```

I set the variable in the environment section of the handler. The file functions/my-function/index.ts is

```
import schema from './schema';
import { handlerPath } from '@libs/handlerResolver';

export default {
  handler: `${handlerPath(__dirname)}/handler.main`,
  events: [
    {
      http: {
        method: 'post',
        path: 'make-payment',
        request: {
          schema: {
            'application/json': schema
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  environment: {
    CONFIG_TABLE : "${env.CONFIG_TABLE}",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to access process.env. This does read from the .env file and the environment variables.

```
  environment: {
    CONFIG_TABLE : process.env.CONFIG_TABLE,
```

Comment: hey, I was trying to use process.env for some AWS keys, but am unable to do so. when I try to print serverlessConfiguration, it comes as an empty string. how did you resolve it?

Comment: I would not use process.env for keys. Use the AWS variables for that?

Comment: Yes, I've used this process extensively. I don't use it for keys though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72288699/how-can-i-use-process-env-in-serverless-ts
I tried using process.env but it wasn't working for me when I logged the values. please check the attached ques once. I will look into AWS variables, thanks

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this for a bit, I realized that when moving to a typescript configuration, one has to think about environment variables **in the config** a little bit differently.

First, let's make a distinction between two sets of environment variables:

1. deployment configurations
2. function configurations

Let's talk about (2) first, as it's the simplest. Declare these variables in a .env file and set the `useDotEnv` flag. Serverless (or the dotenv plugin) will take care of loading these variables into process.env in your serverless function to be accessible at runtime.

I believe this question would more like to focus on (1). How does one access per-environment variables during deployment configuration?

Answer: You don't use dotenv.

The *only* thing you should be setting is your STAGE variable:

```
STAGE=dev sls deploy
```

This allows you to access `process.env['STAGE']` at deployment time to customize your deployment per stage.
Here's an example of how one could abstract this in your serverless.ts file.

```
interface Stage {
  SomeVariable: string
}

const stages: {
  [env: string]: Stage
} = {
  dev: {
    Foo: 'bar',
  },
  qa: {
    Foo: 'baz',
  },
}

const stage = stages[process.env['STAGE'] ?? '']

if(!stage) {
  throw new Error("STAGE=[dev|qa] sls deploy")
}
```

You can now access your per-environment configuration in your Serverless definition.

This has the following advantages:

- type safety
- separation of deployment options vs runtime options
- co-location of your deployment options across environment
- you can move this code into another module and import it
- you can follow the same strategy for runtime environment variables, but I'll save that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Angular does it this way with environment ts files. Clearly people smarter than me think this way. The only problem is that .env are useful for hiding things like environment specific keys/end points that you don't want in VCS.

Comment: Agreed. The .env.dev.local is an awesome feature. This is why I'm not enthusiastic about moving function runtime environment variables into typescript. I've found that most of my secrets fall into this other category (for now) and I still leverage dotenv for them. But I don't reference these in a deployment config.