# how can I use process.env in serverless.ts?

Tags: lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

I am using the serverless framework to deploy some REST APIs. Earlier I was using serverless.yml and now migrating to the typescript version. I am having some AWS keys which I would like to keep in env files and not add directly. Earlier I was adding them directly.

I am trying to do something like the below:

```
export const serverless = {
    frameworkVersion: '3',
    useDotenv : true,
    plugins: ['serverless-webpack', 'serverless-offline'],
    provider: {
        name: 'aws',
        runtime: 'nodejs14.x',
        stage: process.env.stage,  // check this
        profile: process.env.stage === 'dev ? 'dev' : 'prod', // check this
        region: process.env.region,
    },
};
```

this is not working. I tried logging the env variables and above object but it's coming as empty. I have already tried using this plugin- https://github.com/neverendingqs/serverless-dotenv-plugin

it seems that, env variables are loaded after serverless.ts file.

should I stick to using - `${self:custom.stage}` syntax. I was trying to avoid this. or Is it possible to use process.env?

Edit:

when trying to use syntax - `${env:profile}`

`Cannot resolve variable at "provider.profile": Value not found at "env" source`

Answer (score 1):

To access env variables in serverless configuration use **${env:VARIABLE_NAME}**. For the stage: for me **${opt:stage}** works when running `sls --stage STAGE_NAME`.

In your case:

```
export const serverless = {
    frameworkVersion: '3',
    useDotenv : true,
    plugins: ['serverless-webpack', 'serverless-offline'],
    provider: {
        name: 'aws',
        runtime: 'nodejs14.x',
        stage: '${opt:stage}', 
        profile: ${opt:stage, 'prod'}, // if no --stage default to 'prod'
        region: '${env:region}',
    },
};
```

Comment: yeah, I know about this syntax. I was trying to avoid it somehow like I said in the last sentence. The reason is, that I was trying to create a wrapper around this in a project.